# Loop over SmtpClient.Send()

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient

I'm working on a ASP.NET (C#) product that has to send unique emails to a list of subscribers. My code looks something like this:

```
// Grab subscribers from db, about 10-20.
var malingList = Bll.GetAllSubscribers();
var client = new SmtpClient(); 
 
// Set up settings on the SmtpClient with cridentails and so on

foreach(var subscriber in mailingList)
{
  var message = new MailMessage(); 
  // Set up message, set reciver, yada yada
  client.Send(message);
}

client.Dispose();
```

I get this error when testing this with the "fake smtp" Papercut: Failure sending mail.Unable to write data to the transport connection:

What I want to do is to keep the SMTP-connection open aka. don't have to reproduce the "handshake" with every e-mail.

I'm not 100 sure but. Should this work? I think I have another project where it's implemented as this.

Comment: `Client.Send(message);` should be `client.Send(message);`

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the `Using (var client = new SmtpClient())` ?

Comment: @James Hill - Yes this was just to show the concept.
@ Erik Philips - Did you read the post? Wraping the lines in a using-statement would call Dispose on each send out. I don't want to send the QUIT-command in each look. I want to keep the connection and reuse it over 10-20 sends, if thats possible. On the other hand, I could wrap the foreach inside the using-statement. Anyway, thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Papercut library will not be able to facilitate the behavior you're looking for because each time you call `Send` it will drop the current connection and establish another connection to the server and do the handshake anyway. Here's the source from their CodePlex repository:

```
public void Send()
{
    string response;

    Connect(session.Sender, 25);
    response = Response();
    if (response.Substring(0, 3) != "220")
        throw new SmtpException(response);

    Write("HELO {0}\r\n", Util.GetIPAddress());
    response = Response();
    if (response.Substring(0, 3) != "250")
        throw new SmtpException(response);

    Write("MAIL FROM:<{0}>\r\n", session.MailFrom);
    response = Response();
    if (response.Substring(0, 3) != "250")
        throw new SmtpException(response);

    session.Recipients.ForEach(address =>
        {
            Write("RCPT TO:<{0}>\r\n", address);
            response = Response();
            if (response.Substring(0, 3) != "250")
                throw new SmtpException(response);
        });

    Write("DATA\r\n");
    response = Response();
    if (response.Substring(0, 3) != "354")
        throw new SmtpException(response);

    NetworkStream stream = GetStream();
    stream.Write(session.Message, 0, session.Message.Length);

    Write("\r\n.\r\n");
    response = Response();
    if (response.Substring(0, 3) != "250")
        throw new SmtpException(response);

    Write("QUIT\r\n");
    response = Response();
    if (response.IndexOf("221") == -1)
        throw new SmtpException(response);
}
```

You could of course change the source to do what you are after considering it is open source.

Comment: but I using papercut as Smtp server for testing. For sending i'm using asp.web.mail-classes. Could it be the server that kills the connection?

Comment: That would be good information to include in your question (Papercut also includes a SMTP client library called SmtpClient, which I assumed your question was regarding). Armed with that information I'll try to reanalyze your problem.

Comment: This is just utterly painful. Their implementation of SMTP varies greatly from ones I've used in the past to the point that I don't think it is standards compliant. If you're looking for an easy way to test a program that sends emails then just go open a free account at Gmail, Live, etc. It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: And I just checked what the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class does internally and it also doesn't keep a persistent connection for its lifetime so it also won't allow what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Just to defend my self I did write "as fake smtp" in the question =D. So you mean i should skip the Pupercut-smtp server when testing? I would like to test this and "capture" the email on the local server.

Comment: About the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient. This means that I would have to create a new smtpclient for each email then?

Comment: I'd need a broader picture of what you're trying to achieve with this in order to help you figure out the best way to capture the emails locally. And, you should be able to use the same `SmtpClient` instance to send multiple emails though it won't provide the benefit you're looking for.

Comment: The local smtp-server is just for testing. The production enviroment will be a web-app. I want to reuse the SmtpClient to save time. The app may send upp to a total of 10k+ of emails. My plan was to send about 20 mails, dispose the SmtpClient, create a new one and countinue like that until the email-que is finished. You said that the SmtpClient dosent keep a persistent connection, but that i could use the same SmtpClient. Does that mean that the SmtpClient will reconnect on every call to the Send-method?

Comment: From what i can se the SmtpClient.Send()-method calls the ReleaseConnection() on the underlaying SmtpTransport-class after each send out. This method seems to be closing the connection to the server. But I'm not 100% sure right now. But why? Whoulden't it be better to keep the connection to allow multiple emails to be sent?

Comment: That is what I saw and is why I don't think it'll work for what you're trying to do. Feel free to roll your own SMTP client implementation.

Comment: Hehe! "Roll my own" whoouu.. sounds like to much work =D Thank you very much for providing great info M.Babcock!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could have some relation with the limitation of the smtp client to send bulk mails. 
Maybe you could dispose the client so now and then, after 20-30 mails?

Answer gotten from:
[Failure sending mail. Unable to write data to the transport connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791453/failure-sending-mail-unable-to-write-data-to-the-transport-connection)

Comment: Thats want I'm doing right now, but this error shows after just 1-2 messages. I suspect that it could have something to do with the Papercut-software or its implementation of the smtp-protocol.